# Reflection : returning wrong fields

Tags: java, android, reflection

I was trying to use reflection API to get the fields of a class, I was doing it by passing the the class as an argument to the following method

```
private void someMethod(Class<?> objClass) throws IOException {
        String className= objClass.getSimpleName();
        Map<String, String> fieldsAndDataType = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Field field : objClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
        {
            String fieldName = field.getName();
            String fieldDataType = field.getType().toString();
            fieldsAndDataType.put(fieldName, fieldDataType);
        }
        Log.d("here","here "+fieldsAndDataType);

    }
```

I am calling the method like

```
someMethod(MyClass.class);
```

But instead of returning me the fields of 'MyClass', The fields which I am getting are :

1. serialVersionUID
2. name

But my class is a simple class with three properties and having primitive dataTypes with some getters and setters only.However the

> String className= objClass.getSimpleName();

is returning me correct class name.

The `someMethod()` is not giving me the member variables of my class.
How can I get them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should replace `objClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` with `objClass.getDeclaredFields()`

`objClass` is the class object of `MyClass`

`objClass.getClass()` is the class object of `java.lang.Class`

You were getting the declared fields in the class `java.lang.Class` in your code

Comment: Awesome.........Thanks,its working,but can you elaborate a little bit that what was being returned to me.