# Gradle - jacoco tasks add synthetic fields when Spring app running, leading failure of tests counting number of declared fields in a class

Tags: java, spring-boot, reflection, junit

I have this class:

```
public class UserPurchaseUtil {
    public static final String JSON_PROP_ID = "id";
    public static final String JSON_PROP_USER_ID = "user_id";
    // See Confluence: First Time Member Promotion (FTM)
    public static final String JSON_PROP_LAST_PURCHASE_TIME = "last_purchase_time";

}
```

Then, I want to ensure that I pay attention to all the value changes in this class, by "pay attention", I want to ensure that

- every time I delete or add some constants, a test will fail;
- all the values are checked.

So I have this test:

```
@Slf4j
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserPurchaseUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void testNumberOfConstantsAndTheirValues() {
        int numberOfConstants = UserPurchaseUtil.class.getDeclaredFields().length;
        // just to ensure we test all the constants' values when we add new ones. Now is 3.
        Assert.assertEquals(3, numberOfConstants);

        Assert.assertEquals("id", UserPurchaseUtil.JSON_PROP_ID);
        Assert.assertEquals("user_id", UserPurchaseUtil.JSON_PROP_USER_ID);
        Assert.assertEquals("last_purchase_time", UserPurchaseUtil.JSON_PROP_LAST_PURCHASE_TIME);
    }
}
```

But, this simple test fails:

```
expected:<3> but was:<4>
Expected :3
Actual   :4
 <Click to see difference>
```

Then, why?

EDIT:

OMG. Now when debugging, I can see the fourth field now.

```
private static transient boolean[] com.xxx.utils.UserPurchaseUtil.$jacocoData
```

This is a Spring Boot project.

[image]

Comment: did you click to see difference?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32644402/259889

Comment: Yes. The difference is: `3` vs. `4`.

Comment: You may be getting the declared fields of `Class` class.

Comment: What you get if you print the content of `UserPurchaseUtil.class.getDeclaredFields()` ?

Comment: Strange.... when I change it to `new UserPurchaseUtil().getClass().getDeclaredFields()` the test passes, but when I do `Arrays.stream(UserPurchaseUtil.class.getDeclaredFields()).forEach((f) -> System.out.println(f));`, I get `public static final java.lang.String com.xxx.utils.UserPurchaseUtil.JSON_PROP_ID` and other two fields printed. Now I am not sure...

Comment: What are you not sure about?

Comment: Use debugger and check what is inside that array to find that unexpected field

Comment: After that, when I check `int numberOfFields2 = Class.class.getDeclaredFields().length;
        System.out.println(numberOfFields2);`, I have `20`.

Comment: Why are you checking Class.class.xx... ?

Comment: See edit guys. Was not expecting `jacoco` interfering. The single test when run passes, but if I run Gradle `test` task, it fails. Oh.

Comment: what does `isSynthetic()` return for that field? maybe it is marked as such.... **Edit**: modifiers 4234 - it is Synthetic, you should only consider non-synthetic fields

Comment: eventually also check for `static`, `final` and non-`private` fields....depending on use case

Comment: @NicholasK I checked that because Sid suggested maybe I was checking the number of fields in `java.lang.Class` instead of `UserPurchaseUtil`, but it turns out not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle `jacoco`-related tasks like `jacocoTestReport` and `jacocoTestCoverageVerification` is interfering my reflection check of all classes.

I found this issue:

https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/168

> **My code uses reflection. Why does it fail when I execute it with JaCoCo?**
>
> To collect execution data JaCoCo instruments the classes under test which adds two members to the classes: A private static field $jacocoData and a private static method $jacocoInit(). Both members are marked as synthetic.
>
> Please change your code to ignore synthetic members. This is a good practice anyways as also the Java compiler creates synthetic members in certain situation.

I think in this case, I should ignore synthetic members when counting. `isSynthetic()` means a member is added at runtime by compiler(sort of).

So it will be like:

```
int nonSynthetic = 0;
Field[] allFields = UserPurchaseUtil.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field f: allFields) {
    // ignore synthetic methods, which are added at runtime by jacoco (or other libraries)
    if (!f.isSynthetic()) {
        nonSynthetic ++;
    }
}
Assert.assertEquals(3, nonSynthetic);
```

Comment: `isSynthetic()` basically means that it hasn’t been declared in the source code, not that it has been added at runtime. It also applies to the fields added by the compiler, e.g. when you have an `assert` statement or for the outer instance of an inner class or for the cached constant array of an `enum` type.

Comment: oh, they are marked as Synthetic too, then your self-answer is better than mine

Comment: Your help surely helps, thanks. I think synthetic methods are barely mentioned and needs more attention?

Comment: By the way, you have to keep in mind that the fields declared in `UserPurchaseUtil ` are compile-time constants. So when you suspect that someone has changed them, you have to ensure that you always recompile your unit test before running, as otherwise, it won’t notice the changes.

Comment: such a  *Déjà vu*

Answer (score 1):

So your class have extra fields added by your libraries, create some list of exceptions to ignore fields that matches some names/patterns.
Maybe just ignore transient fields? Or only get public fields?