# Junit : org.junit.ComparisonFailure issue , additional of $jacocoData +XXXX is getting added while mvn clean install

Tags: java, junit, testcase

Tes cases are getting filled while doing `mvn clean install`, error is getting generated with below code while running test cases

> OfferUtils.createJsonRequest.

reason for error is, additional string **$jacocoData +XXXX** is getting added to the data, ls check the error section I have formatted for better understanding

note:inquiryRequest is getting build while reading json file from resource directory , it is well tested and used in my classes in my project.

```
 my test cases:
 @Mock
 InquiryRequest inquiryRequest;
 @Test
 public void TestCreateOeidpJsonRequest() throws Exception {
                         Assert.assertEquals(OfferUtils.createJsonRequest(inquiryRequest),
                    "{\"addresses\":[{\"zipCode\":\"92602\",\"country\":\"US\",\"city\":\"IRVINE\",\"state\":\"CA\",\"line1\":\"32 CAPISTRANO\"},{\"zipCode\":\"11063018\",\"country\":\"US\",\"city\":\"LONGMEADOW\",\"state\":\"MA\",\"line2\":\"LAWNWOOD AVE\",\"line1\":\"23\"}],\"names\":[{\"firstName\":\"KEVIN\",\"lastName\":\"SEO\"}],\"phones\":[{\"number\":\"1234567890\",\"type\":\"r\"}],\"requestor\":{\"companyID\":\"27657\",\"subscriberCode\":\"1910000\",\"purposeType\":\"4B\"}}");
                        }
```

Error :

> org.junit.ComparisonFailure:    expected:
> <...S","city":"IRVINE",
>
> ```
> "[$jacocoData":"[Z@1320998",
>                         
> "state":"CA","line1":"32 CAPISTRANO"},{"zipCode":"11063018","country":"US","city":"LONGMEADOW",
>                         
> "$jacocoData":"[Z@1320998",
>
> "state":"MA","line2":"LAWNWOOD AVE","line1":"23"}],"names":[{"firstName":"KEVIN","lastName":"SEO",
>
> "$jacocoData":"[Z@34b1b78a"
>
>                         }],"phones":[{"number":"1234567890",
>
>                         "$jacocoData":"[Z@d8462dd",
>
> "type":"r"}],"requestor":{"companyID":"27657",
>
> "$jacocoData":"[Z@2f34a133]",
>
> "subscriberCode":"...>
> ```

but was:

```
    <...S","city":"IRVINE",
    "[state":"CA","line1":"3
    2 CAPISTRANO"},{"zipCode":"11063018","country":"US","city":"LONGMEADOW","state":"MA","line2":"LAWNWOOD AVE","line1":"23"}],"names":[{"firstName":"KEVIN","lastName":"SEO"}],"phones":[{"
    number":"1234567890","type":"r"}],"requestor":{"companyID":"27657]","subscriberCode":"...>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle - jacoco tasks add synthetic fields when Spring app running, leading failure of tests counting number of declared fields in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855176/gradle-jacoco-tasks-add-synthetic-fields-when-spring-app-running-leading-fail)